# Graphics Bug on Main Site (but not on Meta?)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

Did somebody fiddle with the site design of the parent gaming site recently? I came home from class today and found the following:
[image]

I even made sure to use free-hand MS Paint circles...

The graphics bug persists through F5 and manual refreshes, seems to affect many icons (including up / down arrows). All links are still clickable, and I can still upvote, for example, just missing.

Most irritating is the complete and utter lack of the Ask Question(TM) ship.

The meta site is showing up normally as well, so I'm confused.

I'm using Chrome, and haven't had this problem before.

Edit: I also appear to be unable to post comments to this question, which isn't a graphics bug, but is still weird.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that bug here with Chrome on Win 7. Did you clear your cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't reproduce this. I suggest clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Yup. That fixed it. I was under the impression that that was what the F5 key did, but after manually clearing the cache (and fixing the problem) it appears I was mistaken.

Comment: @Raven try Ctrl+F5 next time.